# Django 1.6.1 + MySQL + Apache 2.4.7 on Windows. Is it possible?

Tags: python, mysql, django, windows, apache

I've just installed the last `apache` release `httpd-2.4.7`, next I istalled the last `python 3.3.3` release, then I added `mod_wsgi` and restarted `apache` - so, at this point everything is ok. At the next stage I downloaded the last release of `django 1.6.1` and also installed it (`python setup.py install`). Now I want to connect `mysql` (the version does not really matter for me) and `python`, but do not now how  and do not know if it is possible. The catch is, I want not only to connect `python` and `mysql`, but also `django` and `mysql` (I heard, it is possible to have `python` and `mysql` connected, but `django` and `mysql` disconnected). So, I need two simplest instructions: 1) How to connect `python` and `mysql` 2) How to connect `django` and `mysql` - the simplest example would be enough.

Comment: This question makes no sense at all. There's no such thing as a "connection" between MySQL and Python in the sense you seem to be using. And Django is just Python. In any case, full instructions on getting Django to talk to mysql are in the docs.

Comment: The case is, I worked with PHP for several years and make my first steps with python. So, it's quite ok, that I do not know some terminology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`MySQLdb`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mysql-python/) (the native driver for MySQL) is not compatible with Python3 yet; but the driver from Oracle for MySQL, called [MySQL Connector/Python](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/python) is compatible with Python 3.

You should use the Oracle driver. django works with both.

Once you have the driver installed, follow [the connection section](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/databases/#connecting-to-the-database) in the documentation.

Comment: Thank you, sir! You gave perfect instructions!